# Make overflow automatically go down every few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that scroll would automatically go down a little bit every few seconds and that would expose more text. Is it possible to do that? By overflow I mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bnfkv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer that relaunches itself it there is anything left to do:

```
function scroll() {
    $('#x').animate({ scrollTop: '+=5px' }, 100, function() {
        if($('#x table').height() - this.scrollTop - $('#x').height() > 0)
            setTimeout(scroll, 500);
    });
}
scroll();
```

And an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2PpyJ/

Note that I added `id="x"` to your HTML to make it easier to reference the `<div>`.

Comment: is it possible to do instead of `scrollTop: '+=5px'` show new tr?

Comment: @hey: Yes, you'd just have to figure out how tall the next row is and use that instead of 5. My example was meant to demonstrate the scrolling so I picked 5px to get something noticeable but small enough to make the animate run for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myElement = document.getElementById(.......); // or use jquery
var scrolling = setInterval(
    function() {
        //pick one:
        //myElement.scrollBy(0,1); // if it's a textarea or something
        //myElement.scrollTop = myElement.scrollTop+1; // if it's a DIV
    }, 
    10 // every 10ms
);
```

To stop it:

```
clearInterval(scrolling);
```

Comment: Could you please demonstrate it in jsFiddle?